# pushnotification not working when server changes

Tags: php, iphone, push, push-notification

I was developing an application with push notification enabled. It is working perfectly in the local server (company server - PHP), but when I change the server to the client server, the push notification is not working.

I used both the development and distribution profile with push notification enabled.

Please help me to overcome this situation.

Comment: Have you put .pem file to server????

Comment: go through my answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/16274256/362310][1]
This might also be useful for you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16274256/362310

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are still using a Development Certificate when your client has a Ad Hoc (or App Store) provisioned App?

If your client has the App provisioned / signed for Ad Hoc (or App Store) then you need to use the Production certificate to send Push Notifications via the APNS.  You also need to make sure you connect to the Apple's production server, and not the sandbox alternative.

It seems a little odd that Ad Hoc has to use the production versions of Certificate and Push Notification server, but that's how it is.