# Apple Push Notification not working on shared server

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I want to send APN (Apple Push Notification) from PHP script. My PHP script is working fine and I receive notification in the iphone device as well when sending from localhost but when I upload the same script with same .pem file to the `shared server` it returns error...

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection refused) in /mypath/SendPushNotification.php on line 28 Failed to connect: 111 Connection refused
```

From some source I get to know that to send APN port 2195 must be open which is not possible in the shared server plan. So I tried using dedicated server and it's working perfectly and I receive the notification on the device. I tried hard to find the solution for shared server but didn't find any solution.

My question: is it possible send APN without opening port 2195 from shared server? if Yes give some guidance.

Comment: please check your certificate (.pem) or regenerate certificate (.pem) and try again.

Comment: @Pratik it's just working perfectly on local machine as well as on dedicated server then what issue should it have on shared server?

Comment: then may be problem in your shared server's SSL Port

Comment: @Pratik yes, that's the question how do I do it on shared server?

Comment: you should have to open SSL port it is must required for Push Notification

Comment: tell to your service provider to open SSL Port

Comment: @Pratik I did, they're approaching for dedicated server...

Comment: look this question it may be help to you   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811919/how-to-check-connectivity-of-apns-port-2195-from-my-hosting-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Its not possible to send APN message without using 2195 port.

If you want to send push notification message from shared server, try using some third party tools  like http://urbanairship.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I got the same error, and then I found that it ocurres because of the server, the proxy is blocking that port, because most of servers doesn't use that port as a common one(80 or 21).

In this case you could try asking for support on your server reseller , they can open that port (2195) for you, If your take this solution I would recommend also asking to open the port 2196 that port is used for feedback.

Another solution is to use a free push notification provider, like Parse which is really easy to use and implement on your app, also you can use UrbanAirship, but I preffer Parse ;)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is irritating and definitely `port 2195` issue. Chat with your hosting provider and ask them to open the port. I also had same issue. My Local code was running peacefully in every condition like `sandbox` and `production` but it was failing on the server.

Dont get confused about `.pem` file path and that would be simple corresponding to your code. For me i put my `certificates (.pem)` in a directory named **certs** and gave path like this:

```
$apnsCert = 'certs/cert_prod.pem';
```

The code was not working on my apps production server. I wasted one and a half day on this but that ran great on first run when i put that on application's staging server. Reason!!!! Definitely `port 2195` issue.

All the beat.